# fstatfs android native system call

Tags: android, system, call, native

Is there a reason why fstatfs fails on android versions before 3.0 and actually works on honeycomb.

I can imagine that it is a security issue but is there a reason why this is added on honeycomb and not previous versions

Thanks.